# Private beta testing a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Is there a way of beta testing a Chrome extension in the Web Store among a small group of users?

I'd like to do this before scaling to everyone on my waiting list, but I don't want to have to send round the file with installation instructions, especially given that Google is tightening up on extensions that aren't downloaded from the Web Store.

It'd also be useful to be able to slowly roll it out (à la Mailbox) if that's at all possible.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Publishing on Chrome Web Store has 3 (well, 4) options:

- **Public.** The extension will be listed in search and gallery, everyone can install and use.
- **Unlisted.** The extension will not be listed in search and gallery, but everyone with a direct link can install.
- (Google Apps domains only) **People with accounts on [example.com] only.** This allows to publish items privately, as long as you administer a Google Apps domain.
- **Private.** The item will only be available to a selected list of Google accounts, or a Google Group. Note that this is aptly aliased as "Trusted Testers".

That said, you most probably have 2 options:

1. Have a restricted set of accounts that can use your app. CWS allows to either specify an explicit but short list, or to link with a Google Group you administer.
2. Use "unlisted" and send everyone the link. Use only if you don't care if the link leaks: you won't be able to remotely kill any install.

Note that if you have enough (10000+) users you can do [partial rollouts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37139555/934239) of regular updates, to have less impact from problematic updates if they happen.

Comment: What if I already have an extension that is being used by thousands of people, but I'd like to do a beta testing without updating anyone's installation before going live with the new version?

Comment: @AlexStack I maintain a separate version and ask testers to install that instead; I roll the updates on the beta first, wait a few days for problem reports, and then roll on the stable. That said, if your extension has enough users, there's a feature that will appear on your update draft - partial rollout. You can specify a percentage of (randomly selected) users that will get the update - useful if you want to prevent mass breaking.

Comment: I have an app in beta test now. I use the "unlisted" option, ie. only/all those with the link can install it. But additionally I use a registration code which is tested against a server side PHP script. Only if that code match, the App will start. The code is stored in the app's local storage space so the user won't have to enter the code again (the code is persistent across updates). When the app is finally released, the code won't be needed anymore.

Comment: I added a few testers and they installed the app. Now I removed them from testers. As you said there is no way to remotely kill their installs, how do I then make sure that only current testers use my application?

Comment: @Rishav You don't. You only control who can install a new copy.

Comment: @Xan one issue with running a second version is when doing oauth the app id changes which changes the redirect callback, resulting in you not testing the correct settings.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must be stupid or something. I have checked the "unlisted" option for my new extension. What is the link I should share to testers? I only see the ID of the extension.

Comment: @ClaraAttermo Is the item's status in https://chrome.google.com/webstore/devconsole/ listed as "Published - unlisted" (i.e. review is passed)? If yes, you can open the web store listing as https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/yourExtensionIdHere - and that's the link you need to send to testers.

Comment: @Xan, oh, so the review needs to be passed first. That explains things. Thanks for the answer.