# Releasing beta versions for Chrome Apps

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Is there any way that I could release a beta version for my Chrome Packaged App prior to final release?

Testers should be able to install it without going to developer mode.

My request differs from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033335/private-beta-testing-a-chrome-extension) as I am looking for a different way of publishing on the same platform which will provide a public link to my users in order to update to a beta version.

Comment: I don't think the process is different from extensions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23033335/934239

Comment: My app is already unlisted. People having link installed it. But some of them want an update for some certain bugs. Yet current version is not ready for relase. What I can see from this post is, I dont actually have an option that satisfies what I want.

Comment: You will have to have a second listing for "advance" versions.