# chrome store extension private rsa key

Tags: google-chrome-extension, pem

I uploaded an extension to the chrome store without generating a .pem for it. I want however to distribute the package independently of chrome store to beta testers as well. Is there a way to get the private key that google assigned to my extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's [sadly impossible](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/faq#faq-listing-06).

Besides, consider that Windows version of Chrome will refuse packaged extensions from sources other than CWS.

Comment: Thank you! I understand I can define tester accounts for an extension that are the only ones who can see it, but do you know is there a way only for the testers to see the "development" version of the extension while the rest of the world to see the stable version?

Comment: I solve this by just having a separate version, unlisted (no auth, so it's a semi-public beta).

Comment: A more in-depth look at beta-testing possibilities: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23033335/934239